# Tag suggestion: "best practices"

Tags: discussion, tags

After asking a question about [types of dishwasher detergent](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/9950/), I realized that I see a lot of questions asking the "best way" to do something. For example:

- [**Best way** to store vegetables in the fridge](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/best-way-to-store-vegetables-in-the-fridge)
- [**Best way** to dry hands](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/best-way-to-dry-hands)
- [What's the **best way** to dispose of scrap lumber?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/7169/whats-the-best-way-to-dispose-of-scrap-lumber)
- [**Best way** to vent smoke from stove, without room for a hood](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/5577/best-way-to-vent-smoke-from-stove-without-room-for-a-hood)
- [How can we use fallen leaves from tree in **best way**?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/799/how-can-we-use-fallen-leaves-from-tree-in-best-way)

Aside from those with "best way" in the title, there are [56 posts](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22best+way%22) talking about the "best way" to do something or other.

**How about a [best-practices](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) or [environmental-best-practices](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environmental-best-practices) to apply to these posts?** This would help differentiate between questions about items and their use, and would be convenient to point people to. For instance, when someone asks about replacing their car, we could point them to posts tagged [best-practices](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) and [cars](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) to make sure they're doing everything they can with their current car.

If folks agree, we could create and feature a meta post announcing the tags creation, and go tag all the appropriate questions.

Comment: I worry that such a tag would be overly broad. In general I don't like tags that apply to more than 20% of questions. I [wrote about this](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/317/1236) on the Meta for vegetarianism.

Comment: On the other hand... a quick skim suggests that we have many questions not about best practices, so perhaps this could be a workable tag. It would need an excellent tag wiki excerpt though.

Comment: Another concern is that if nobody has ever tried to introduce this tag among 50+ related questions, is it really an in-demand tag that people will think of when asking or searching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be such a tag on Stack Overflow, but [it was black listed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60118/tag-block-request-best-practice)
after Jeff's blog post "[The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)", which by the way explicitly mentions the former best-practices tag.
The problem is that questions asking for "the best" are often not the best questions. To answer them you would need to compare your proposed solution with all other available options which is not always possible, and consequently [answers tend to be subjective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275039/why-is-the-best-practices-tag-not-allowed). Additionally it is questionable if many people will use the tag because meta-tags do not describe the topic of the question very well.

On the other hand, Sustainable Living SE is a different site than Stack Overflow. Here it is very common to ask about "the most sustainable" product or service which is basically the same.

Overall I'm inclined to say no, we shouldn't create such a tag, but I'm not 100% against experimenting.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the blog. I realize that the key points ("the tag means different things to different people" and "the tag can't stand by itself") do apply here. Your concern about the tag not being used is also valid.